# How can I open the URL in my script in a background tab?

Tags: autohotkey

So I have this code:

```
f9:: 
Send, ^c
Run, msedge.exe http://www.google.com/search?q="%clipboard%"
return
```

And I want to make a version of this script where the URL is opend in a background tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps look at the Help for Run as follows:  https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm

```
FROM THE HELP (this is not the code, but only explanation):
Syntax: Run, Target , WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID
Parameters: Options
Min: launch minimized or Hide: launch hidden
```

So your code (that one line anyway) would be:

```
Run, msedge.exe http://www.google.com/search?q="%clipboard%", , Min
```

And that should do it!  But if it doesn't (some windows don't respond to those options) then just wait a bit and minimize the window as follows:

```
Run, msedge.exe http://www.google.com/search?q="%clipboard%", , Hide
Sleep, 3000 ; timing in ms so 3 seconds is probably more than you need
WinMinimize, %clipboard% ; since the window title will include it
```

Enjoy,